# Java, NIO, one thread with reading and writing

Tags: java, thread-safety, nio

I try to build simple client application sending data to server and receiving data from it .
In most of time it'll asynchronic exchange  data (beside logging process)

I've read a lot of tutorials, posts etc. but I can't find enough description for me (i'm newbe in java) how to construct code for:

- reading/writing (simple line -string with "\n" at the end),
- reconnecting (if errors found)

client  with server (I've wrote it in another development environment), all in one thread?

Could somebody help me by giving simple example or addreess where can I find out about simple using NIO in presented purposes? All examples I found treated only for reading or writing (not mixed) or simple connect, send data and disconnect without explanation exception, reconnection.

Comment: Can you show your code of how much you have done, and what is your specific problem? This was too many question in one post.

Comment: NIO is not a good choice for line-oriented protocols, or for clients either. I would use BufferedWriter and BufferedInputStream, and a couple of threads.

Comment: Thank you. I could't found the good tutorial about NIO and Android (it is my destination platform of java) therefore I try hard to use ordinary sockets and two threads (reading and sending data). But I have problem with synchronize them - I mean a specialy moment of error and needing reconnect (close connection and set it again): two competing threads fight each other (when one has error and try reconnect the second one can be ok). How to synchronize this to avoid fighting problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you get an exception on a socket it is dead and must be closed, unless it was a read timeout. I don't know why you think 'the second one can be OK'.

Comment: I mean two threads receive exception in the same time and when the first one will be try reconnet, the second will want to do it too and it will be classic death lock. I can not find way for this second one, to know that process new connection is in progress and it has to skip this to avoid problem.

Comment: See this answer, it has a simple client NIO with request-response messaging in a single main thread. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26312841/185565

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an NIO problem, it's just an inter-thread communications problem.

The second thread will get the same exception the first one did, and it can look at a `reconnectPending` boolean that can be set by the first thread while it reconnects the socket.